# Return object of a function doesn't export to Excel in PowerShell

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm using the `Export-Excel` cmdlet to export the output of a function into Excel. My function is as follows:

```
function SQLQuery($ServerName, $DBName, $Query)
{
    $SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$ServerName;Database=$DBName;Integrated Security=True"
    $SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $SqlCmd.CommandText = $Query
    $SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection
    $SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    $SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
    $DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
    $Output = $DataSet.Tables[0]
    $SqlConnection.Close()
    return $Output
}

$ResultCost = SQLQuery -ServerName $SName -DBName $DBName -Query (Get-Content -Path $CostQueryPath)

$ResultCost.Table | Export-Excel -Path $ReportPath
```

The direct output doesn't get exported to Excel so I used `$ResultCost.Table` to export. However, I see many duplicates being exported (if the result has 10 records, the `$ResultCost.Table` has 10 to the power of 10 i.e., 100 records). How can I export only the direct output? And how do I remove the last 5 unwanted columns?

Comment: I would recommend sticking to one question at a time. For example, if you want to filter out duplicates from a list of objects, you can use `Sort-Object -Unique`.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't get exported ? What happens when you try it ? What remove  last 5 unwanted columns ? I am guessing you don't want specific columns in your result ? If so, simply remove them from your QUERY

Comment: `$ResultCost.Table | Sort-Object -Unique | Export-Excel -Path $ReportPath`

doesn't export all of the records from the output. But exports only 1 records

Comment: My query doesn't have those columns selected. They automatically appears after exporting. Below are the column names that gets exported.
_RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors_

Comment: Also, instead of trying to remove duplicates, can I understand what is the reason for the duplicates when there are no duplicates in the output of the query? _if the result has 10 records, the $ResultCost.Table has 10 to the power of 10 i.e., 100 records_

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to export a dataset to a .xlsx file try exporting the rows, not the table.

So instead of `$ResultCost.Tables | Export-Excel -Path $ReportPath`

Try `$ResultCost.Tables.Rows | Export-Excel -Path $ReportPath`

Comment: Additionally if you are trying to remove the 5 rows that Export-Excel seems to add at the end, just remove them with a select statement.

Comment: Code: `$ResultCost.Tables.Rows | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError,RowState,Table,ItemArray,HasErrors | Export-Excel -Path $ReportPath`